# How do I stop a method if model cannot find a solution within timelimit?

Tags: python, mips, gurobi

I have a complex MIP model in Python, solve with Gurobi, and long program to run. Usually, I run it and then write the output (values of variables, solution parameters, etc.) to a file. For large instances, the model does not find any solution within the time limit, and then logically gives me an error when I try to retrieve values for variables, which stops the whole code. In this case, I would like it to skip the output section. I tried to achieve this by only writing the output if model.Params.SolutionCount != 0. However, it still gives me the same error of trying to retrieve the variables within the if-statement. Is there any other way to tell Python to skip code if there is no solution without interrupting the program completely? Thank you!

Comment: Show your code?

Answer (score 0):

You should always check the solution status before trying to query solution values. This can be like this:

```py
...
model.optimize()

if model.status == GRB.INF_OR_UNBD:
    # Turn presolve off to determine whether the model is infeasible
    # or unbounded
    model.setParam(GRB.Param.Presolve, 0)
    model.optimize()

if model.status == GRB.OPTIMAL:
    print('Optimal objective: %g' % model.objVal)
    model.write('model.sol')
    sys.exit(0)

elif model.status != GRB.INFEASIBLE:
    print('Optimization was stopped with status %d' % model.status)
    sys.exit(0)
```

This is taken from the [Gurobi documentation](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/examples/lp_py.html).

Comment: Thank you, but  my problem then is that model.status != GRB.INFEASIBLE does not distinguish between a solution was found and no solution was found, if the status is Timelimit reached. In the first case, I would like to still print my solution, in the latter case, however, that causes an error. So I need to find a way to, once the status is timelimit reached, to have an if condition that only is true if no solution was found, which is why I tried model.SolCount == 0. How can I do it?

Comment: If there is a feasible solution, then model.SolCount is positive and you should be able to query that solution. You should share an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you! I realized now that it works as long as the if model.SolCount==0 works as soon as it is within the  model.status != GRB.INFEASIBLE , so the problem is solved.